# Why does the current warm spell in the Pacific Northwest include high, thin clouds?

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting

I've noticed this during summers (lived here since birth). Sometimes there will be cloudless blue skies, other times when it gets warm there will be a layer of thin clouds, often with higher humidity levels and uncomfortably warm nights. I took a picture of what I mean on Friday.[image: overcast]

My guess is monsoonal flow that can't develop into thunderstorms due to high pressure aloft.